# eclipse の Maven の更新実行時にエラーが発生する

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven

現在 eclipse を用いて Spring Framework で開発をしているのですが、
Maven の更新実行時にエラーが発生してしまいます。

「"artifactId-domain を検証中" 中に内部エラーが発生しました。」
のような、日本語が少しおかしいですが、このようなエラーメッセージが出ております。

また、例外スタックトレースを以下に記載します。

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.frameworks.core.util.StringUtils.hasLength(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)Z
at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.xml.namespaces.util.DocumentAccessor$SchemaLocations.initSchemaLocations(DocumentAccessor.java:115)
at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.xml.namespaces.util.DocumentAccessor.getCurrentSchemaLocations(DocumentAccessor.java:82)
at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.xml.namespaces.internal.ProjectClasspathExtensibleUriResolver.findSystemIdFromFile(ProjectClasspathExtensibleUriResolver.java:281)
at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.xml.namespaces.internal.ProjectClasspathExtensibleUriResolver.resolve(ProjectClasspathExtensibleUriResolver.java:104)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.uriresolver.internal.ExtensibleURIResolver.resolve(ExtensibleURIResolver.java:86)
at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.validation.ValidatorHelper$MyContentHandler.startElement(ValidatorHelper.java:299)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$ContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.validation.ValidatorHelper.computeValidationInformation(ValidatorHelper.java:177)
at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.validation.XMLValidator.validate(XMLValidator.java:337)
at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.validation.eclipse.Validator.validate(Validator.java:95)
at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.validation.core.AbstractNestedValidator.validate(AbstractNestedValidator.java:283)
at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.validation.core.AbstractNestedValidator.validate(AbstractNestedValidator.java:88)
at org.eclipse.wst.validation.Validator$V2.validate(Validator.java:1178)
at org.eclipse.wst.validation.internal.ValManager.validate(ValManager.java:704)
at org.eclipse.wst.validation.internal.ValManager$1.visit(ValManager.java:665)
at org.eclipse.wst.validation.internal.ValManager.accept(ValManager.java:810)
at org.eclipse.wst.validation.internal.ValManager.validate(ValManager.java:669)
at org.eclipse.wst.validation.internal.ValBuilderJob$Visitor.visit(ValBuilderJob.java:299)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.lambda$1(Resource.java:117)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.lambda$0(Resource.java:85)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.doIteration(ElementTreeIterator.java:85)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.doIteration(ElementTreeIterator.java:90)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.doIteration(ElementTreeIterator.java:90)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.doIteration(ElementTreeIterator.java:90)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.doIteration(ElementTreeIterator.java:90)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.doIteration(ElementTreeIterator.java:90)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.doIteration(ElementTreeIterator.java:90)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.iterate(ElementTreeIterator.java:135)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.accept(Resource.java:94)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.accept(Resource.java:55)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.accept(Resource.java:117)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.accept(Resource.java:105)
at org.eclipse.wst.validation.internal.ValBuilderJob.fullBuild(ValBuilderJob.java:219)
at org.eclipse.wst.validation.internal.ValBuilderJob.run(ValBuilderJob.java:178)
at org.eclipse.wst.validation.internal.ValBuilderJob.runInWorkspace(ValBuilderJob.java:126)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

artifactId-domain の pom.xml は以下のようになっております。

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>artifactId-domain</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.example.artifactId</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <!-- == Begin TERASOLUNA == -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.terasoluna.gfw</groupId>
        <artifactId>terasoluna-gfw-common-dependencies</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.terasoluna.gfw</groupId>
        <artifactId>terasoluna-gfw-jodatime-dependencies</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.terasoluna.gfw</groupId>
        <artifactId>terasoluna-gfw-security-core-dependencies</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.terasoluna.gfw</groupId>
        <artifactId>terasoluna-gfw-mybatis3-dependencies</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.terasoluna.gfw</groupId>
        <artifactId>terasoluna-gfw-recommended-dependencies</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <!-- == End TERASOLUNA == -->

    <!-- == Begin Database == -->
    <!-- <dependency> -->
    <!-- <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId> -->
    <!-- <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId> -->
    <!-- <scope>test</scope> -->
    <!-- </dependency> -->
    <!-- <dependency> -->
    <!-- <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId> -->
    <!-- <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId> -->
    <!-- <scope>test</scope> -->
    <!-- </dependency> -->
    <!-- == End Database == -->

    <!-- == Begin Unit Test == -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- REMOVE THIS LINE IF YOU USE Spring Test DBUnit <dependency> <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId> <scope>test</scope> </dependency> <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.springtestdbunit</groupId> <artifactId>spring-test-dbunit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope> </dependency> -->
    <!-- == End Unit Test == -->

    <!-- == Begin Coding Support == -->
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId> <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope> </dependency> -->
    <!-- == End Coding Support == -->

</dependencies>
```

また、親の pom.xml は次のようになっております。

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.example.artifactId</groupId>
<artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.terasoluna.gfw</groupId>
    <artifactId>terasoluna-gfw-parent</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<name>Macchinetta Server Framework (1.x) Web Blank Multi Project</name>
<description>Web Blank Multi Project using Macchinetta Server Framework (1.x)</description>
<url>http://macchinetta.github.io</url>
<inceptionYear>2017</inceptionYear>
<licenses>
    <license>
        <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
        <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
        <distribution>manual</distribution>
    </license>
</licenses>
<organization>
    <name>Macchinetta Framework Team</name>
    <url>http://macchinetta.github.io</url>
</organization>
<developers>
    <developer>
        <name>Macchinetta</name>
        <organization>Macchinetta</organization>
        <organizationUrl>http://macchinetta.github.io</organizationUrl>
    </developer>
</developers>
<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:git@github.com:Macchinetta/macchinetta-web-multi-blank.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:Macchinetta/macchinetta-web-multi-blank</developerConnection>
    <url>git@github.com:Macchinetta/macchinetta-web-multi-blank</url>
</scm>
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-failsafe-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${org.codehaus.mojo.build-helper-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>src/generated/java</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-resource</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-resource</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/generated/resources</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-war-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>${project.artifactId}</warName>
                    <archive>
                        <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>artifactId-domain</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>artifactId-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>artifactId-env</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<properties>
    <!-- == Maven Plugin Versions == -->
    <maven-war-plugin.version>2.5</maven-war-plugin.version>
    <org.codehaus.mojo.build-helper-maven-plugin.version>1.9.1</org.codehaus.mojo.build-helper-maven-plugin.version>
    <maven-failsafe-plugin.version>2.19</maven-failsafe-plugin.version>
    <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.17</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
    <!-- == Dependency Versions == -->
    <postgresql.version>42.2.9</postgresql.version>
    <ojdbc.version>19.3.0.0</ojdbc.version>
    <dbunit.version>2.5.4</dbunit.version>
    <spring.test.dbunit.version>1.3.0</spring.test.dbunit.version>
    <!-- == Project Properties == -->
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    <java-version>1.8</java-version>
</properties>
<modules>  <module>artifactId-env</module>
<module>artifactId-domain</module>
<module>artifactId-web</module>
<module>artifactId-initdb</module>
<module>artifactId-selenium</module>
```

クリーンやリフレッシュは試しましたがエラーは消えませんでした。

なお、このエラーに類似したエラーは eclipse 起動時やエクスプローラのドキュメントを開いた際にも発生するため、非常に困っております。

どなたか、原因・解決策をご存じでしたら、ご回答をお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

例外スタックトレースで名指しされているメソッドは[これ](https://github.com/spring-projects/eclipse-integration-commons/blob/4.8.0.RELEASE/org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.frameworks.core/src/org/springsource/ide/eclipse/commons/frameworks/core/util/StringUtils.java#L62)です。

おそらくEclipseプロジェクトが[Spring Toolsプラグイン](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spring-tools-4-aka-spring-tool-suite-4)前提で構成されているのに対し、質問者の環境がそうなっていないのが原因かと思われます。

開発環境がどうあるべきかは開発プロジェクトによって異なるので責任者に確認してください(複数人で開発している環境下で発生している問題かと考えますが、開発プロジェクトの方針と異なる方向で解決するとまた別の問題の種になります)。

次のいずれかの方向で指示があるのでは無いかと思います:

- 上記プラグインをインストール/アップグレードする(あるいは[セットアップ済みIDE](https://spring.io/tools)を利用する)
- Eclipseワークスペースを新しく作りMavenプロジェクトをimportし直すことで、上記プラグイン導入を前提としない環境をセットアップする

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。

述べておりませんでしたが、個人でのシステム開発中でした。

この他にも色々エラーが発生したため、eclipse の最新版をインストールし
Spring Tools の最新版をインストールしたところ、
エラーの発生が収まりました。

大変助かりました、ありがとうございます。